# Problema ao inserir dados no banco de dados Firibird

Tags: java

estou com esse erro quando vou inserir dados no banco de dados.... vou mandar o codigo e o erro ... desculpem sou novato

```
conexao banco /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controle;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConexaBD {
    public Statement stm; // pesquisa no banco
    public ResultSet rs; // armazena resultado da busca
    private String driver = "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver" ;// identifica serviço do banco
    private String caminho = "jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.0.5/3050:192.168.0.5:c:/cartorio/cartorio/controle livro/CONTROLE_LIVRO.GDB";
    private String usuario = "SYSDBA ";
    private String senha = "cont10rol";
    Connection con;// conexao do banco

    public void conexao(){
        try {
            System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", driver);
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, usuario, senha);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "conexao efetuada com sucesso");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao se conectar como o banco de dados:\n"+ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void executasql (String sql){
        try {
            stm = con.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao executa sql:\n"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void desconecta(){
        try {
            con.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"BD desconectado com sucesso");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erro ao fexar BD\n"+ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

inserir dados

```
package controle;

import Modelo.ModeloCancelamento;
import Modelo.ModeloLivro;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ControleLivro {
     ConexaBD conex = new ConexaBD();
     ModeloLivro mod = new ModeloLivro();

   public void Salvar(ModeloLivro mod){
       conex.conexao();
         try {                                                                                                                                          
             PreparedStatement pst = conex.con.prepareStatement("insert into livro(cd_inicial,cd_final,livro,folha_inicial,folha_final,escrevente,data_livro,situacao_livro,dataLivroDate) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
             pst.setString(1,mod.getCodigoInicial());
             pst.setString(2,mod.getCodigoFinal());
             pst.setInt(3,mod.getLivro());
             pst.setInt(4,mod.getFolhaInicial());
             pst.setInt(5,mod.getFolhaFinal());
             pst.setString(6,mod.getEscrevente());
             pst.setString(7, mod.getDatalivro());
             pst.setString(8,"UTILIZADO");
             pst.setString(9,mod.getDataBancoLivro());


             pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Dados iseridos com sucesso"); 
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao inserir dados"+ ex);
         }

       conex.desconecta();
   }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Eu olharia essa linha:

```
pst.setString(9,mod.getDataBancoLivro());
```

Verificar se é `String` ou se deveria ser `DateTime`.

Comment: eu mudei ate tirei fui tentar inserir 1 dado so .... mais nao vai o erro e o mesmo